# Inverse of cubic function

Tags: javascript, math, interpolation, spline

I'm trying to create the inverse transform of the following function:

```js
function cubic(x, p1, p2) {

  // coefficients
  const cY = 3 * (p1 - 1);
  const bY = 3 * (p2 - p1) - cY;
  const aY = -1 - cY - bY;

  return 1 - ((aY * pow(x, 3)) + (bY * pow(x, 2)) + (cY * x) + 1);

}
```

The function expects `x` to be in the range of 0-1 and returns `y`.

I need to find the inverse of this function to create a curve that is mirrored across the diagonal such that the blue and red curves in the below example produce a perfectly symmetrical shape.

I've tried to invert the transform via `1 - cubic(1 - x, p1, p2)`, switching p1 and p2, negating p1 and p2 etc but nothing is giving me the correct results. Any help greatly appreciated!

[Here's a Javascript Sandbox for the problem on JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/on1490ek/)

[image: Left side shows my current inverse function (red) which is naive and wrong. Right side shows an approximate drawing of the correct inverse transform (green)]

```js
const p1 = 0.65;
const p2 = 1.2;

draw(cvs.getContext('2d'), {
  blue: cubic,
  red: inverse,
  grey: linear
});

function cubic(x) {

  // coefficients
  const cY = 3 * (p1 - 1);
  const bY = 3 * (p2 - p1) - cY;
  const aY = -1 - cY - bY;

  return 1 - ((aY * Math.pow(x, 3)) + (bY * Math.pow(x, 2)) + (cY * x) + 1);

}

// TODO: Correct inverse of the above forward transform
function inverse(x) {
  return 1 - cubic(1 - x, p1, p2);
}

function linear(x) {
  return x;
}

function draw(ctx, fx) {

  const w = ctx.canvas.width * devicePixelRatio;
  const h = ctx.canvas.height * devicePixelRatio;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)';

  const blockWidth = w / 10;
  const blockHeight = h / 10;

  for (let x = 0; x < w; x += blockWidth) {
    for (let y = 0; y < h; y += blockHeight) {
      ctx.strokeRect(x, y, blockWidth, blockHeight);
    }
  }

  for (const color in fx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    for (let i = 0, x, y; i < w; i++) {
      x = i / (w - 1);
      y = 1.0 - fx[color](x);
      ctx.fillRect(Math.round(x * w) - 1, Math.round(y * h) - 1, 2, 2);
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs" width="768" height="768" style="background:black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: The diagonal is y=x. Suppose your function is f(x). When you say 'mirror' image, do you mean you want g(x) such that f(x) + g(x) = x, or the true 'mirror' along y=x such that for every point on y=x, the distance to f() on the right at a right angle, is equal to the distance to g() on the left at a right angle?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I've added an image to the post that shows the desired g(x) as a green curve. It's an approximate drawing. Every imaginary point in the green curve should have equal distance to the diagonal as the corresponding point in the blue curve.

Comment: I see, so you want g(x) = (cubic^-1(x), x) where cubic^-1 is the inverse function such that cubic^-1(cubic(x)) = x . Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation for a general solution to the cubic equation.

Comment: In fact your cubic isn't really a general cubic. You could have written return -x*(x*((aY * x) + bY) + cY) ); So you only need to solve a quadratic.

Comment: No, sorry that's wrong. you want (x, g(x)) with g(x) = cubic^-1(x) which to solve, you will need the general cubic roots equation.

Comment: Thank's so much for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of such a cubic may not even be a function.

But you can at least plot it by swapping the coordinates

```
   y = myfunc(x);
   plot(x,y, 'blue');  // your original function
   plot(y,x, 'green'); // this is the inverse of x,y along the line x-y=0
```

Comment: Or all real numbers.  Possible to be imaginary.